# weird results from flatlist in react native with touchable opacity

Tags: reactjs

I have a FlatList in a React Native project. The touchable opacity does register as the view loads, for each row, the console prints selected item.name..  (so, without being touched) however, touching the item does not do anything.

```
render() {
  return(
        <FlatList
          data={stores.databaseStore.sites.slice()}
          keyExtractor={ (item, index) => item.id}
          numColumns={1}
          extraData={stores.databaseStore.isLoadingSites}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={stores.databaseStore.isLoadingSites}
          renderItem={({item}) => this._renderFlatListItem(item)}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this._renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter}
        />
  )
}


_renderFlatListItem(item) {
  return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showSiteDetails(site)}>
          <View style={styles.cellLeft} >
              <PivotCircle site={item}/>
          </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

  )
}

_showSiteDetails(site){
 console.log(`selected ${site.name}`);
}
```

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPressItem={() => this._showSiteDetails(site)}>

Comment: thanks, but it is doing the same thing

Answer (score 5):

found it with the help of some gents on slack

```
onPress={this._showSiteDetails(site)}
```

should be

```
onPress={ () => this._showSiteDetails(item)}
```